# Device/OS inconsistencies in GLSL ES Phong shader results

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, fragment-shader

[Apple's Best Practices for OpenGL ES](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW12) recommend against branching on results calculated in a fragment shader. But [Phong shading](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Specular_Highlights) generally involves skipping the specular term when the light source is on the "wrong" side of the surface, for which the straightforward approach is to dot the unit normal direction `N` and light direction `L` and check for a positive result.

I attempted to do this without a branch in my shader: instead of using an `if` statement, I do all the calculations for the specular term and then give it a coefficient which is `1.0` if `dot(N, L)` is greater than zero and `0.0` otherwise. (I achieve this using the builtin `step()` function. Combining `max()` and `sign()` produces the same results but is said to be a bit slower.)

However, this appeared to lead to odd, device- and/or iOS version-specific, results:

[image: with branch][image: without branch]

- On my iPhone 4 running iOS 6.0, the version with the branch has a wide specular highlight (left image); without the branch I see a narrow specular highlight (right image), despite the "shininess" exponent remaining the same.
- On the iOS 6.0 Simulator, I see the second image with both versions of the shader.
- On my iPad (original 2010 model, stuck at iOS 5.1), I see the first image with both versions of the shader.

Clearly, it's not the branching or lack thereof that's the problem. (The right-hand image is the "correct" rendering, by the way.)

Here's my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform lowp vec3 ambientLight;
uniform lowp vec3 light0Color;
uniform lowp vec3 materialAmbient;
uniform lowp vec3 materialDiffuse;
uniform lowp vec3 materialSpecular;
uniform lowp float materialShininess;

// input variables from vertex shader (in view coordinates)
varying vec3 NormDir;
varying vec3 ViewDir;
varying vec3 LightDir;

void main (void)
{
    vec3 L = normalize(LightDir);
    vec3 N = normalize(NormDir);
    vec3 E = normalize(ViewDir);

    lowp vec3 ambient = ambientLight * materialAmbient;

    float cos_theta = dot(L, N);

    lowp vec3 diffuse = materialDiffuse * light0Color * max(0.0, cos_theta);

    lowp vec3 specular = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
//  if (cos_theta > 0.0) {
        lowp vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);
        lowp vec3 V = normalize(-E);
        float cos_alpha = dot(R, V);
        specular =  step(0.0, cos_theta) *  materialSpecular * light0Color * pow(max(0.0, cos_alpha), materialShininess);
        //          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        //          should produce the same results as the commented branch, right?
//  }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0);
}
```

I welcome further suggestions for improving this shader's performance on iOS hardware, too!

Comment: Could this be a precision artifact? I know that I've seen significant differences in the way that lowp values are rounded between the various iOS devices. In particular, I wonder if the use of lowp for some of the values leading to `cos_alpha` and `materialShininess` couldn't cause odd things to happen in your `pow()` operation. I don't think that using mediump there would slow you down too much.

Comment: Both approaches are not completely equivalent. 
step(0.0, cos_theta) is equivalent to "if(cos_theta >= 0)", as step() returns 1 when cos_theta = 0 because (0.0 < 0 ) is false. but i don't think that's making the difference anyway.

Comment: It took awhile for me to find time to experiment with this some more, but @BradLarson is right: the precision on `materialShininess` is it. Once that's `mediump`, the device/OS inconsistencies go away and all render the "correct" way (right-hand image). (Really, the branch/no-branch stuff turned out to be a red herring.) Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @BradLarson If you don't want to post it as answer i can do it too! ;-)

Comment: @BradLarson You should really post this as an answer, it is one of those things that is quite difficult to learn from theory alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in @BradLarson's comment, the `lowp` qualifier on `materialShininess` turned out to be the problem; with that set to `mediump` instead, it renders correctly (right-hand image) on all devices and OS versions I have on hand, regardless of whether the branch or no-branch (with `step`) version of the shader is used.

(Using `lowp` versus `mediump` for the inputs `R` and `V` from which `cos_alpha` is calculated doesn't make any visible difference, which makes sense: those are normalized vectors, so their components have magnitudes in the range 0.0 to 1.0. That's the same range as color components, for which `lowp` seems to be intended.)